# Is there a cleaner/simpler way of doing an equivalent of WHERE a IN (aa, bb, cc)?

Tags: c#, linq

Anyone knows if there is a cleaner/simpler way of doing the equivalent ?

Also, any side-effects I should watch out for ?

```
var setters = from setterBase in Style.Setters
              let setter = (setterBase as Setter)
              let properties = new []{ HorizontalContentAlignmentProperty, VerticalContentAlignmentProperty }
              where setter!=null && properties.Contains(setter.Property)
              select setterBase;
```

So far it the best I have come up with...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to new up an array for every setter.

```
var properties = new []{
  HorizontalContentAlignmentProperty,
  VerticalContentAlignmentProperty };

var setters = from setter in Style.Setters.OfType<Setter>() 
              where properties.Contains(setter.Property) 
              select setter;
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that 'let' recreates the array each time, I forgot that one...  This can have a major impact depending on the size of the two collections ('properties' and 'setter')

Comment: If properties has much size to it, consider using a HashSet instead of an array.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. For two options it's probably more readable to use `or`, and you can use `OfType` instead of the `as`-cast and first `let`. `OfType` will not return `null` elements, so you can remove that filter as well:

```
var setters = from setter in Style.Setters.OfType<Setter>()
              where (setter.Property == HorizontalContentAlignmentProperty ||
                     setter.Property == VerticalContentAlignmentProperty)
              select setter;
```

Comment: Nice! I was just rewriting using OfType<> as well. When using OfType, you don't need the null check, right?

Comment: @Robert - I'm not sure - the collection *might* contain `null`s, but you can probably remove it.

Comment: (setter != null) is redundant as null will never evaluate to being of type Setter.

Comment: If there are nulls in the collection, they will not be of type Setter. :)

Comment: You are both correct, I wasn't sure and just tested it to confirm. Thanks!

Comment: In case there is a lot of values to compare setter.Property againts I find your answer would be more verbose but that was not my question :)

Comment: @smichaud - in case you have many values it may be better to create the collection before the linq statement, so keep it short and readable.

Comment: @Kobi - Yes, that was for the purpose of making a small/contained exemple, putting everything in the LINQ query makes more clutter, which is the opposite of my goal.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this. I still like having the properties in an array to easily support more properties. Nice!

```
var setters = from setter in Style.Setters.OfType<Setter>()
              let properties = new []{ HorizontalContentAlignmentProperty, VerticalContentAlignmentProperty }
              where properties.Contains(setter.Property)
              select setter;
```